# Get scancode rather than keycode on Linux using X11

Tags: linux, input, x11, xlib, scancodes

I'm trying to listen to keyboard input (using an X11 event loop) and get scancodes. These scancodes should refer to the physical location of a key, rather than the character it types. The problem is, all I can get are KeySyms and KeyCodes, which are mapped differently for different languages (QWERTY vs QWERTZ for example).

My current solution is to read the "/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev" file. It contains the mappings of key locations to key codes. Using this I can simply translate any keycode back to a scancode. My guess is this is not a stable way of doing things though. I don't know much about Linux at all. That's why I thought asking here might be a good idea.

Is it safe to assume the these evdev mappings are being used by most user's machines? If not, where else could I find key mappings that are actually being used? Or is there a better solution to all of this?

Comment: The very idea that a key has a fixed physical location depends on one particular implementation of character input. People may use virtual keyboards where they are free to rearrange keys themselves. Or handwritten input or voice recognition or... In any of these cases, there's no physical locations associated with keys. Even if there is a physical keyboard with scancodes, there are many incompatible models, see other files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes`.

Comment: That makes sense. Let's say we ignore any special input methods other than traditional keyboards. If any of the files in "/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes" could be used for mapping, is there a way to detect which a of them is used by a device?

Comment: You can obtain physical location of keys by examining keyboard geometry. Run `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10` and you will see a geometry include statement. Examine files in X11/xkb/geometry (most probably one named "pc"). You will also see which mapping is in use. I don't know programmatic equivalent to `setxkbmap -print` but there definitely is one. I'm not sure what happens if the user remaps his keyboard with xmodmap, but I'd say let them deal with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and I've just found a solution. Let's start with the obvious first.

If you want to get specific keys such as "W" or "4", no matter where they're located, you can just convert the keycode you receive from the event into a KeySym. In this case "W" is `XK_W` and `XK_w` and "4" is `XK_4` (and `XK_dollar` on most keyboards).

However, sometimes you want to get keys such as "the n<sup>th</sup> key of the m<sup>th</sup> row". You need key names to do that. In this case "W" is `AD02` and "4" is `AE04` on QWERTY keyboards.

Let's say you are making a game in which the player needs to use the WASD keys to move. If you look for KeySyms it's going to work fine on QWERTY keyboards, but people using other keyboard layouts such as AZERTY, QWERTZ and DVORAK will have trouble. So in this case it's better to use key names.

Using key names is actually pretty easy, but the [documentation](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/XKB/xkblib.html) is very messy (but I still recommend you take a look at it). I had to take a look at [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/)'s source code (specifically [src/x11_init.c](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/src/x11_init.c)) because I was clueless. This method requires Xkb, but you were already using it so I guess that's no problem.

First you need to get the keyboard map and obtain symbolic names. We only want key names so we use `XkbKeyNamesMask`.

```
#include <X11/XKBlib.h>

XkbDescPtr KbDesc = XkbGetMap(XDisplay, 0, XkbUseCoreKbd);
XkbGetNames(XDisplay, XkbKeyNamesMask, KbDesc);
```

Then, at the event loop you can use the KbDesc->names->keys array to get the key name for a specific keycode:

```
XEvent Event;
XNextEvent(XDisplay, &Event);

switch (Event.type)
{
case KeyPress:
    /* I'm not sure this 'if' is necessary, but better safe than sorry */
    if ((Event.xkey.keycode >= KbDesc->min_key_code) && (Event.xkey.keycode <= KbDesc->max_key_code))
    {
        /* Copy key name into Name */
        char Name[XkbKeyNameLength + 1];
        memcpy(Name, KbDesc->names->keys[Event.xkey.keycode].name, XkbKeyNameLength);
        Name[XkbKeyNameLength] = '\0';   /* Null terminator */

        if (strcmp(Name, "AD02") == 0)   /* Is it W (for QWERTY and QWERTZ) / Z (for AZERTY) / comma (for DVORAK) / ц (for Russian) etc... ? */
        {
            /* Do something... */
        }
        else if (strcmp(Name, "AE04") == 0)   /* Is it 4 (for most keyboards) / whatever's in its place? */
        {
            /* Do something... */
        }
        /* ... */
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

And that's it. It seems to work pretty well so far. I'd like to mention that special keys have very different key names. For example, Left Shift is `LFSH`, Left Control is `LCTL`, Space is `SPCE` and Escape is `ESC`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: How would I know that key "AD02" maps to key W on a QWERTY keyboard? Also from where to get the list of key names like AD02?

Comment: @KaranJoisher Either by testing or googling. Best reference I've found is GLFW's source, specifically [line 253 in x11_init.c](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/src/x11_init.c#L253). Even though GLFW uses symbols such as `GLFW_KEY_W`, it should always be equivalent to the key in that physical space. So, for an AZERTY layout, `GLFW_KEY_W` would be equivalent to the Z key. I still strongly recommend testing, though.