# Ubuntu, C++, xkb/symbols files: Is there a mapping between keynames and keycode?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, keyboard, key, keycode

In usr/share/x11/xkb/symbols/ there are files for definitions of key of a keyboard e.g. usr/share/x11/xkb/symbols/us:

```
key <AD01> {    [     q,    Q       ]   };
key <AD02> {    [     w,    W       ]   };
key <AD03> {    [     e,    E       ]   };
key <AD04> {    [     r,    R       ]   };
key <AD05> {    [     t,    T       ]   };
key <AD06> {    [     y,    Y       ]   };
```

- Where key <AD01> is a ***name of the key***.
- When working with x11 I want to use ***keycodes***.

**Is there a mapping of name of keys to keycodes available or do i need to figure them out  myself?**

I am looking for something like

- <AD01> --  24
- <AD02> --  25
- <AD03> --  26

Comment: AD01 is the _position_ of the key.  `D` means fourth row up from the bottom.  `01` means second key.  (`AD00` would be the Tab key on most keyboards.)  This Q&A may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552572/4641116